# ¿Existe una onomatopeya en español para el sonido de murmurar?

Tags: onomatopeyas

Los dibujos animados y cómics en japonés usan sonidos parecidos a "fts fts" o "bts bts" como onomatopeya para cuando un personaje está murmurando. ¿Existe algo así en español? O si no, ¿cómo se podría traducir?

Comment: Yo creo, aunque no lo puedo comprobar, que la palabra murmurar es onomatopéyica, por lo tanto pordría ser **mur** o **murmur**, aunque la palabra, por lo que se, proviene del griego....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En inglés existen varias, como *mumble-mumble* o *buzz buzz*, o de plano la palabra "whisper" entre comillas.

En español no la he visto tanto, pero [este artículo](https://repositori.upf.edu/bitstream/handle/10230/27831/Marquez_2016.pdf) de Cristina Márquez Prieto indica que

> **bis-bis**, **bss**, y **chau-chau** pueden ser utilizadas como onomatopeyas
>
> [image: .pdf]

Comment: @Mike, entiendo bis-bis, pero ¿chau-chau?  Se oye como la frase para despedirse en italiano, *ciao ciao*.  Eché un ojo al artículo y no ví ninguna documentación de ese cuadro.

Answer (score 6):

En la entrada del DLE para «bisbisear» puedes leer:

> [bisbisear](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5ba7W48)
>   De la onomat. *bisbís*, imit. del sonido del cuchicheo.

De lo cual inferimos que una de las onomatopeyas reconocidas es **bisbís** (a pesar de que no venga con tal acepción [si la buscas directamente](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5bXgxk2)).

Aunque si lo que quieres es traducir algo, yo personalmente usaría **[bisbiseo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5bcPPID)**.